# jQuery cannot get custom attributes on UL elements

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, prop

I am currently focussing the following issue with jQuery 1.8.2.

Custom attributes are working fine for e.g. input fields:

```
<input id="test" required="true">

$("#test").prop("required")

true

$("#test").get(0).required

true
```

But not with UL elements.

```
<ul id="test" required="true"></ul>

$("#test").prop("required")

undefined

$("#test").get(0).required

undefined
```

Any ideas why it does not work with UL elements in Firefox 16 but in MSIE 8? Thanks!

Comment: Does `required` for an `ul` element make sense?

Comment: I have specific "Checklist" inputs and the UL is the "group".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to use custom attributes for one reason or another, check out HTML5 `data-` attributes.

```
<ul id="test" data-required="true"></ul>

console.log($('#test').data('required'));
```

http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Comment: That answer helped me out most. It works on both MSIE 8 and Firefox 16. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's because HTML5 `required` is a valid property for input elements and jQuery returns the value of this property, and for an `ul` element `required` is just an invalid attribute. An `ul` element has no `required` property, so it's undefined.

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-required-attribute

Comment: This answer is almost correct. However, made-up attributes, such as asdf, got the same issue

Comment: There is a vast difference between an attribute and DOM property.

Answer (score -1):

You must use:

```
$('#test').attr('required')
```

Comment: when you alert this it return `required`

Comment: No, this just returns required independent of the value (true/false)

Comment: You are right, I didn't test it. This is how I do it when I use custom attributes in my code. Sorry, for the incorrect answer.

Comment: I¡ve checked, and this is correct. When a html element has the "required" attribute, is value is meaningless.